# Variable names in Python using numbers

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to concat numbers stored in a variable and using it as variable names in Python (or interpolated as a string). Something like this:

```
for NUMBER in range(2000, 2020, 1):
    df_NUMBER = pd.read_csv('data_NUMBER.csv')
    df_NUMBER['year'] = NUMBER
```

is it possible?

In stata it would be like:

```
forvalues NUMBER = 2000(1)2019 {
    import delimited using data_`NUMBER'.csv
    generate year = `NUMBER'
}
```

Comment: Technically it can be done (in a very convoluted way), but what's wrong with just using a dictionary?!

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically generate variable names? This is a very bad idea. Can you show your intended output and also explain why you want to do it? Or are you asking how to create a string with a changing number in it in order to reference different file names? If that latter, it is trivial with string interpolation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables. You can only really do it in global scopes, not local scopes, and it is **almost certainly** a poor design decision.

Comment: poor design but if you want to do this and learn the hard way, I think that falls on you! here is what you'd put inside your loop: `exec("df_%d = pd.read_csv(\'data_%d.csv\')" % (NUMBER, NUMBER))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try create variable names dynamically, it is a very bad idea. Rather just store the dataframes in a collection. In this case a dictionary might make sense. Otherwise just a single longform dataframe which will make analysis easier:

option 1:

```py
dfs = {}
for year in range(2000, 2020):
    dfs[year] = pd.read_csv(f"data_{year}.csv")
    dfs[year]["year"] = year
```

option 2:

```
dfs = []
for year in range(2000, 2020):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"data_{year}.csv")
    df["year"] = year
    dfs.append(df)
df_all = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

You probably want option 2 in this case as you can then go on to perform your analyses on all the years at once using `.groupby("year")`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going the dictionary way:

```
df = {}
for year in range(2000,2020):
    filename =  'data_{}.csv'.format(year)
    df[year] = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df[year]['year'] = year
```

Comment: In `range(2000,2020,1)`, you don't need the last parameter because the default step is already 1.

Comment: Right, I just copy-pasted from the OP's question.